# random timer in settimeout (in for loop) is not accurate

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

```js
     for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) { setTimeout(function(ind) { return function() { 
       let start = Date.now()


        $('.output').append(
          "<div class=\"notify_box\">THIS IS THE BOX NUMBER"+ind+"</div>"
         ).hide().fadeIn(1000);

        // fadeout / remove existing notify box  (3 seconds) and call another box 
        setTimeout(function(){ 
         $('.notify_box').fadeOut("slow")
        }, 2000);

       console.log(Date.now() - start)  
     }; }(i), Math.round(Math.random() * (5000 - 3000)) + 3000 *i);  }
```

```css
  .notify_box {
   background:  #9782AF;
   color: #ffffff;
   padding: 8px;
   border-radius: 20px;
   width: 30%;
   position: fixed;
      margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="output"></div>
```

here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gsfe6vm9/

in line 15, the timber seems not to be accurate. I set it to randomly loop for 3 to 5 seconds, but sometimes it pop-ups 1 or 2 seconds.

How can I also console.log the time it pops-up? line 14 seems to be incorrect.

Here's the code I used:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function (ind) {
        return function () {
            let start = Date.now()

                $('.output').append(
                    "<div class=\"notify_box\">THIS IS THE BOX NUMBER" + ind + "</div>").hide().fadeIn(1000);

            // fadeout / remove existing notify box  (3 seconds) and call another box
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.notify_box').fadeOut("slow")
            }, 2000);

            console.log(Date.now() - start)
        };
    }(i), Math.round(Math.random() * (5000 - 3000)) + 3000 * i);
}
```

Comment: `Math.round(Math.random() * (5000 - 3000)) + 3000 *i)` is indeed part of the problem. what happens when `i=0` ?

Comment: please explain what should be the desired behavior?

Comment: Never use setTimeout inside for loop. Even if you want to use it add it inside IIFE and pass `i` as argument.

Comment: @phanther: He/she **is** using an IIFE and passing `i` as an argument to it. (The code formatting makes it really hard to see, but it's there.)

Comment: FYI, providing your runnable example **here, on-site** would make it easier for people to help you. You can do that using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added a running snippet. in line 15, the timber seems not to be accurate. I set it to randomly loop for 3 to 5 seconds, but sometimes it pop-ups 1 or 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I hope with this knowledge you can solve your problem.

```js
for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++) { 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log(i + " second(s) elapsed"); 
    }, i * 1000); 
}
```

The code above is likely intended to output the following messages, with a second of delay between each message:

```
1 second(s) elapsed
2 second(s) elapsed
3 second(s) elapsed
```

But the code actually outputs the following:

```
4 second(s) elapsed
4 second(s) elapsed
4 second(s) elapsed
```

The problem is that console.log(i + " second(s) elapsed"); is in the callback of an asynchronous function. By the time it runs, the for-loop will have already terminated and the variable `i` will be equal to `4`.

There are various workarounds to this problem, but the most common one is to wrap the call to setTimeout in a closure, which will create a new scope with a different i in each iteration:

```js
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    (function (i) { 
       setTimeout(function() {
           console.log(i + " second(s) elapsed"); 
       }, i * 1000); 
    })(i); 
}
```

If you are using ECMAScript6 or later, then a more elegant solution is to use `let` instead of `var`, since `let` creates a new scope for `i` in each iteration:

```js
for(let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i + " second(s) elapsed"); 
    }, i * 1000);
}
```

Read more at [hack.guides()](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript)